# Opening Map Tiles Stored On Google Drive With Google Earth Network Link?

Tags: google-earth, google-drive

I'd like to store a superoverlay or tiled map on Google Drive and then open it in Google Earth via a Network Link.

I've been able to store single KML files on Google Drive and then generate a direct download link via a converter and use that successfully in Google Earth as a network link. But I've been unsuccessful in doing this with map tiles/ superoverlays. The network link in Google Maps, which is to the KML, has a green light, but the children files have red lights.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Superoverlays are made of of many files... all the image tiles and all the linked KMLs which load them at the right zoom/pan levels. Each one of those KML files contains URLs pointing to its image tile and to the KMLs below it.  Unfortunately none of this will work on Google Drive unless you update all those URLs in each file, to be the direct download links instead of the simple relative links.  And since Drive gives each file a unique ID, you would need to generate the unique download URL for each file.  Unless your Superoverlay is only a couple levels deep, this would be a nightmare and not worth the effort.

I encourage you to find another place to host the superoverlays, where all the files can be directly accessed .  If you want to stick with Google tools, try setting up a Google Cloud Storage Bucket, setting it's permissions to Public, and putting your files in there.